# Where does python tempfile writes its files?

Tags: python, linux, temporary-files

In python you can create a tempfile as follows:

```
tempfile.TemporaryFile()
```

And then you can write to it. Where is the file written in a GNU/Linux system? I can't seem to find it in the /tmp directory or any other directory.

Thank you,

Comment: ["Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is removed immediately after the file is created."](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile). Careful with that.

Comment: when I try: mytempfile.name I get:   
"<fdopen>"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at `.name` on a file handle is indeed one way to see where the file exists. In the case of [`TemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) (on *NIX systems), you'll see `<fdopen>`, indicating an open file handle, but no corresponding directory entry. You'll need to use [`NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) if you'd like to preserve the link to the underlying file.

---

If you wish to *control* where temporary files go, look at the `dir` parameter:

[`TemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) uses [`mkstemp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp), which allows setting the directory with the `dir` parameter:

> If `dir` is specified, the file will be created in that directory; otherwise, a default directory is used. The default directory is chosen from a platform-dependent list, but the user of the application can control the directory location by setting the `TMPDIR`, `TEMP` or `TMP` environment variables.

Comment: The file.name returns "<fdopen>". Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. `TemporaryFile` just deals with the OS [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), so there's no accessible file name. If you want a file with an accessible path, use a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile). Reading the documentation for [`mkstemp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) will hopefully shed some light on this and ease any confusion.

Comment: @Loic: It means it is an open file handle and the underlying file has already been unlinked. Use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` if you need a filename.

Comment: @Loic: On POSIX systems, you can unlink a file while you still have a file handle. Your process can read and write to the file, but no other process can access it because the directory entry has already been removed.

Comment: @Loic: This is highly a desirable feature, making your temporary file a secure place to store information that other processes are not supposed to be able to read, let alone write to.

Answer (score 13):

Call the [`tempfile.gettempdir()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir):

> Return the directory currently selected to create temporary files in.

You can change where temporary files are created by setting the [`tempfile.tempdir` value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir) to different directory if you want to influence where temporary files are created. Quoting from the documentation, if that value is `None` the rules are as follows:

> If tempdir is unset or `None` at any call to any of the above functions, Python searches a standard list of directories and sets tempdir to the first one which the calling user can create files in. The list is:
>
> 1. The directory named by the `TMPDIR` environment variable.
> 2. The directory named by the `TEMP` environment variable.
> 3. The directory named by the `TMP` environment variable.
> 4. A platform-specific location:
>
>    - On RiscOS, the directory named by the `Wimp$ScrapDir` environment variable.
>    - On Windows, the directories `C:\TEMP`, `C:\TMP`, `\TEMP`, and `\TMP`, in that order.
>    - On all other platforms, the directories `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, and `/usr/tmp`, in that order.
> 5. As a last resort, the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

on the shell try this

```
    $python
>>> import tempfile
    >>>tempfile.gettempdir()

'/var/folders/5r/lxh8g5ln7zg43_l_3t0j7b1c0000gn/T'
```

This will show you the actual temp path python is using.

You can optionally try this. (this will produce the same result as above)

```
    $python
>>> import tempfile
    >>>tempfile.tempdir
'/var/folders/5r/lxh8g5ln7zg43_l_3t0j7b1c0000gn/T'
```

Comment: `tempfile.tempdir` is set when you call `tempfile.gettempdir()`; `temfile.tempdir` will start out `None`.