# How to select the disk location for UploadFile parameter in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am running FastAPI application on a embedded device. The embedded device has limited resources (disk space and RAM). However, an SD card with plenty of space is available. I would like to upload and store a large file on the SD card. The [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile) suggests using `UploadFile` parameter.

I tried a simple application:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

... and after posting a large file, I get a response with status code `400` and body
`{"detail": "There was an error parsing the body"}`.

I was monitoring disk usage during the upload process and I saw the free space on partition `/tmp` was decreasing until it ran out of space. I assume FastAPI figures out that the uploaded file is too big to be stored in memory and decides to store it on disk. Unfortunately, the selected disk is also too small.

How can I select the location which FastAPI internally uses to store the uploaded file?

Comment: It uses a SpooledTemporaryFile behind the scenes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280245/where-does-python-tempfile-writes-its-files for how you can change where Python's tempfile module stores its temporary files.

Comment: Specificically, looks like you can set the the env variables TMPDIR. TEMP or TMP with your prefered temp directory https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`gettempdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) method from Python's [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module to *get* the default `temporary` directory, as well as use [`.tempdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir) variable to *set*/*change* the default directory used for temporary files.

### Example:

```py
import tempfile

print("Temp directory before changing it:", tempfile.gettempdir())
tempfile.tempdir = "path/to/tempdir/here"
print("Temp directory after changing it:", tempfile.gettempdir())
```