# Error uploading file to google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, fastapi

How should the files on my server be uploaded to google cloud storage?

the code I have tried is given below, however, it throws a type error, saying, the expected type is not byte for:

```
the expected type is not byte for:
blob.upload_from_file(file.file.read()).
```

Although upload_from_file requires a binary type.

```
@app.post("/file/")
async def create_upload_file(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(path.json)
    bucket_name = 'data'
    try:
        bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
    except Exception:
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    for file in files:        
        destination_file_name = f'{file.filename}'
        new_data = models.Data(
            path=destination_file_name
        )
        try:
            blob = bucket.blob(destination_file_name)
        blob.upload_from_file(file.file.read())
        except Exception:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=500,
                detail="File upload failed"
            )
```

Comment: Use **blob.upload_from_filename(file.filename)**

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you, however when I do that, it says given file name is not found, what could be the reason?

Comment: What is the filename? Does it exist?

Comment: it is what is taken from fastapi UploadFile: file = File(...). file.filename exists. but when passed to blob.upload_from_filename(file.filename), it throws error that  "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

As per the documentation, [`upload_from_file()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file) supports a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object; hence, you could use the `.file` attribute of [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) (which represents a [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) instance). For example:

```py
blob.upload_from_file(file.file)
```

#### Option 2

You could read the contents of the `file` and pass them to [`upload_from_string()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string), which supports `data` in `bytes` or `string` format. For instance:

```py
blob.upload_from_string(file.file.read())
```

or, since you defined your endpoint with `async def` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for `def` vs `async def`):

```py
contents = await file.read()
blob.upload_from_string(contents)
```

#### Option 3

For the sake of completeness, [`upload_from_filename()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_filename) expects a `filename` which represents the *path* to the `file`. Hence, the `No such file or directory` error was thrown when you passed `file.filename` (as mentioned in your comment), as this is not a *path* to the file. To use that method (as a last resort), you should save the `file` contents to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which "has a visible name in the file system" that "can be used to open the file", and once you are done with it, delete it. Example:

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

contents = file.file.read()
temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
try:
    with temp as f:
        f.write(contents);
    blob.upload_from_filename(temp.name)
except Exception:
    return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
finally:
    #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
    os.remove(temp.name)
```

#### Note 1:

If you are uploading a rather large file to Google Cloud Storage that may require some time to completely upload, and have encountered a `timeout` error, please consider increasing *the amount of time to wait for the server response*, by changing the `timeout` value, which—as shown in [`upload_from_file()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file) documentation, as well as all other methods described earlier—by default is set to `timeout=60` seconds. To change that, use e.g., `blob.upload_from_file(file.file, timeout=180)`, or you could also set `timeout=None` (meaning that it will wait until the connection is closed).

#### Note 2:

Since all the above methods from the [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage) package perform blocking I/O operations—as can been seen in the source code [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/27f2641c7f6b24ff5e750490f87188e648a82a9e/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L2402), [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/27f2641c7f6b24ff5e750490f87188e648a82a9e/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L2586) and [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/27f2641c7f6b24ff5e750490f87188e648a82a9e/google/cloud/storage/blob.py#L2724)—if you have decided to define your `create_upload_file` endpoint with `async def` instead of `def` (have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on `def` vs `async def`), you should rather run the "upload file" function in a separate thread to ensure that the main thread (where coroutines are run) does not get blocked. You can do that using Starlette's [`run_in_threadpool`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/concurrency.py#L35), which is also used by FastAPI internally (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73365632/17865804) as well). For example:

```py
await run_in_threadpool(blob.upload_from_file, file.file)
```

Alternatively, you can use `asyncio`'s [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and demonstrated in [this sample snippet](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/27f2641c7f6b24ff5e750490f87188e648a82a9e/samples/snippets/storage_async_upload.py#L47) too.

As for Option 3, wehere you need to open a `NamedTemporaryFile` and write the contents to it, you can do that using the [`aiofiles`](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) library, as demonstrated in Option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324461/17865804), that is, using:

```py
async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb", delete=False) as temp:
    contents = await file.read()
    await temp.write(contents)
    #...
```

and again, run the "upload file" function in an exterrnal threadpool:

```py
await run_in_threadpool(blob.upload_from_filename, temp.name)
```

Finally, have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) on how to enclose the I/O operations in `try-except-finally` blocks, so that you can catch any possible exceptions, as well as close the [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) object properly. `UploadFile` is a temporary file that is deleted from the filesystem when it is closed. To find out where your system keeps the temporary files, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71377044/17865804). Note: Starlette, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804), uses a [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) with 1MB `max_size`, meaning that the data is spooled in memory until the file size exceeds 1MB, at which point the contents are written to the temporary directory. Hence, you will only see the file you uploaded showing up in the `temp` directory, if it is larger than 1MB and if `.close()` has not yet been called.

Comment: Thank you very much for the all mentioned options, and for your time. However, there is still an "Internal server error" when I try to upload large files (up to 1 GB) with provided solutions, do you think I should send them as chunks? or the reason is something else?

Comment: It was related to the default timeout limit of upload_from_file(). initializing it to None solved the problem. Thank you very much for your response again.