# How to pass a video uploaded via FastAPI to OpenCV VideoCapture?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, fastapi

I am trying to upload an mp4 video file using  `UploadFile` in `FastAPI`.
However, the uploaded format is not readable by OpencCV (`cv2`).

This is my endpoint:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

@app.post("/video/test", response_class=PlainTextResponse)
async def detect_faces_in_video(video_file: UploadFile):
    
    contents = await video_file.read()
    print(type(video_file)) # <class 'starlette.datastructures.UploadFile'>
    print(type(contents)) # <class 'bytes'>

    return ""
```

and the two file formats (i.e., `bytes` and `UploadFile`) are not readable by OpenCV.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added code up

Comment: @Chris no I will discard it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass either the file `contents` (`bytes`) or `UploadFile` object; however, [`VideoCapture()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ac4107fb146a762454a8a87715d9b7c96) accepts either a video `filename`, capturing device or  or an IP video stream.

[`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) is basically a [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object) that operates similar to a [`TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile). However, it does not have a visible name in the file system. As you mentioned that you wouldn't be keeping the files on the server after processing them, you could copy the file contents to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) that "has a visible name in the file system, which can be used to open the file"  (using the `name` attribute), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804). As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

> Whether the `name` can be used to open the file a second time, while the
> named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be
> so used on Unix; **it cannot on Windows**). If delete is `true` (the
> default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

Hence, on Windows you need to set the `delete` argument to `False` when instantiating a `NamedTemporaryFile`, and once you are done with it, you can manually delete it, using the `os.remove()` or `os.unlink()` method.

Below are given two options on how to do that. **Option 1** implements a solution using a `def` endpoint, while **Option 2** uses an `async def` endpoint (utilising the [`aiofiles`](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) library). For more details on the difference between `def` and `async def`, as well as the `run_in_threadpool` function used in Option 2, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77941425/17865804). If you expect users to upload rather large files in size that wouldn't fit into your server's RAM, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) on how to read the uploaded video file in chunks instead.

### Option 1 - Using `def` endpoint

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

@app.post("/video/detect-faces")
def detect_faces(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    try:
        try:
            contents = file.file.read()
            with temp as f:
                f.write(contents);
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
        finally:
            file.file.close()
        
        res = process_video(temp.name)  # Pass temp.name to VideoCapture()
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error processing the file"}
    finally:
        #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
        os.remove(temp.name)
        
    return res
```

### Option 2 - Using `async def` endpoint

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from fastapi.concurrency import run_in_threadpool
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import os

@app.post("/video/detect-faces")
async def detect_faces(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        async with aiofiles.tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb", delete=False) as temp:
            try:
                contents = await file.read()
                await temp.write(contents)
            except Exception:
                return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
            finally:
                await file.close()
        
        res = await run_in_threadpool(process_video, temp.name)  # Pass temp.name to VideoCapture()
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error processing the file"}
    finally:
        os.remove(temp.name)

    return res
```