# How to Use Pyshark to Read a .pcapng file's content directly from memory instead of from disk?

Tags: python, fastapi, binaryfiles, packet-capture, pyshark

I am using the file capture API of pyshark like this.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding:utf-8
import pyshark as ps
filename: str = 'some_file.pcapng'
with ps.FileCapture(input_file=filename) as capture:
       print(capture[0].pretty_print())
```

But now, I have another use case where the file content can be made available to me only as an array of bytes, or as [UploadFile class of FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/).

Basically, the user (frontend) will upload the pcapng file and then I need to read it as an array of packet, getting the same capture object I can get from a pcapng file stored locally. If necessary, I can read the file content as byte in memory as well, like this.

```py
file: UploadFile = File(default=...) # Obtained from front-end
file_content:bytes=await file.read()
```

So how to get the capture object from the user uploaded file? I had the idea of dumping the file_content on disk as a temporary file and then reading it via `FileCapture`, which is clearly suboptimal and bug prone. But even that is not working.

So is there a way to get the capture object directly from in-memory bytes via pyshark? I tried:

```py
capture=ps.InMemCapture(file_content) # Failed because capture is of length 0
```

but it failed to read any packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

As per [Pyshark's documentation on github](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark#other-options):

> **Other options**
>
> - **param** `input_file`: Either a path or a file-like object containing either a packet capture file (PCAP, PCAP-NG..) or a TShark xml.
> - ...

Hence, `FileCapture` class can take as `input_file` a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object as well, which you can access using the `.file` attribute of the `UploadFile` object. As per [FastAPI's documentation on `UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile):

> `UploadFile` has the following attributes:
>
> - `file`: A [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) (a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object). This is the actual Python file that you can pass directly to other functions or libraries that expect a "file-like" object.
> - ...

Thus, you could try passing the actual Pyhton file instead, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73811351/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71478057/17865804). Example:

```py
@app.post('/upload')
async def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture(file.file)
    # ...
```

### Option 2

Alternatively, you can copy the contents of the uploaded file into a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886990/17865804). Unlike `SpooledTemporaryFile`, a `NamedTemporaryFile` "is guaranteed to have a **visible name** in the file system", which can be used to open the file. That name can be retrieved from the `.name` attribute (i.e., `temp.name`). Example is given below (if you would like to use `NamedTemporaryFile` in an `async def` endpoint, have a look at Option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324461/17865804) on how to do this):

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/upload')
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    try:
        try:
            contents = file.file.read()
            with temp as f:
                f.write(contents);
        except Exception:
            return {'message': 'There was an error uploading the file'}
        finally:
            file.file.close()
            
        cap = pyshark.FileCapture(temp.name)
    except Exception:
        return {'message': 'There was an error processing the file'}
    finally:
        #temp.close()  # the `with` statement above takes care of closing the file
        os.remove(temp.name)  # Delete temp file
    
    return {'filename': file.filename}
```

---

I would also suggest you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804), to understand how FastAPI/Starlette handles uploading files behind the scenes.